# DataGridViewComboBox drop down list does not show any items for selection, drop down doesn't work

Tags: c#, datagridviewcombobox

In a `DataGrid`, I  have one `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. I have assigned a `DataTable` as a `DataSource`,  items ,value member and display member in the code but the `ComboBox` shows up empty when I run the program.The drop down doesn't work at all.

It does however assign the value properly which shows that the `DataSource` was setup properly.i.e when I assign a value , it fetches the correct display member.

Things I have already tried based on other related posts
- using `List` instead of `DataTable` [ works exactly the same]
- using `enum` instead of `DataTable` [  works ok ]
- used the `DataTable` object through a `BindingSource`
- checked for "read only" = false  on all rows ,columns , cells.
- as a precaution assign "read only" = false on `cell_enter` function for the particular column and set the `DataSource` if it is `null`.

When I watch the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`[or column] in debug I see that the items have been populated.
I am truly out of ideas, any help is appreciated.
I have pasted a few code snippets if it helps

```
DataTable data = new DataTable();
data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Value", typeof(string)));
data.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));

data.Rows.Add("en_US", "English-US");
data.Rows.Add("de", "german-Germany");

(patientGrid.Columns[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).Items.Add("English-US");
(patientGrid.Columns[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).Items.Add("german-Germany");
(patientGrid.Columns[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueType = typeof(string);

(patientGrid.Columns[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DataSource = data;
(patientGrid.Columns[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).ValueMember = "Value";
(patientGrid.Columns[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).DisplayMember = "Description";


//setting value 
(patientGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = 
    clientLanguagePreference[cmbClients.SelectedItem.ToString()];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add: patientGrid.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].ReadOnly = false;

Answer (score 0):

In Designer click the little arrow (topright corner) and click Edit Columns. Select the ComboBox and set Read Only field to false